# In python h2o module, how to specify na_strings while using h2o.import_sql_select() to import data?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, h2o

I'm trying to import data from a mysql table into a H2oFrame using `h2o.import_sql_select()`. I'd like NULL or empty values in VARCHAR columns in the database to be recognized as NAs when imported into the  H2oFrame, but they are being considered as empty string literals. However, for numerical columns, NULL values are automatically recognized as NAs.

Here's the code I have:

```
select_query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'
train_data = h2o.import_sql_select("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_schema", select_query, "username", "password", use_temp_table=False)
```

`train_data['my_string_column'].isna()` always results in zeros even for NULL or empty values coming from the database.

However when I dump the data to CSV and import it using `h2o.import_file('/path/to/file.csv', na_strings=[''])` and then do `train_data['my_string_column'].isna()`, I can see that the empty values are correctly recognized as NAs because of the `na_strings` parameter.

Is there some way of specifying `na_strings` or some other work around to achieve the expected behavior while importing data using `h2o.import_sql_select()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no such feature is implemented. This is is simply because contrary to CSV where there is no difference between and empty string and NULL, SQL has the notion of NULL so no such feature seems necessary.

But you are saying that for string columns you are not getting any N/A values in your H2O Frame, which sounds like a bug and I will look into it.

Comment: Honza, I'm sorry there was a problem with my SQL statement and I got misled by it (the example I gave was made up for illustration purposes as I cannot reveal my actual SQL which is very complex). I tried a simpler import and was able to confirm that the problem was not with H2O. NULL values are in fact recognized as NAs. It's just that when you preview a H2O Frame on the python console, there is no distinction between NAs and empty values for string columns. Whereas for numeric columns, NAs are explicitly printed as 'nan'. It makes sense for it to be that way though.